# How is this website able to determine my country?

Tags: web-browser, firefox, geolocation

Today I wanted to visit https://scp-wiki.wikidot.com/scp-4999 to conduct some *scientific research*. Upon loading the page, I was greeted with a text saying Russia (the country I'm in) and Belarus are blocked from visiting this website.

This is all cool and completely understandable, but it made me wonder how exactly the website was able to determine my country of origin, since

- I'm using a VPN server in Netherlands (self-hosted, AmneziaWG protocol)
- I'm using a DNS service on that same server
- My "preferred languages" in my browser (which is Firefox) only list English
- Various "ip leak"-type websites correctly place my IP in NL
- No WebRTC leaks detected
- Nothing from DNS servers seems to leak my location
- This persists through private mode

  - as well as multiple cache purges
  - and across other devices
- NoScript changes nothing
- `geo.enabled` is set to `false`

Without my fix of SCP, my disappointment is immeasurable and my day is ruined.
How does the website do this?

Comment: We are not going to checkout the website to determine what they are doing, but if you look at other questions tagged "geolocation" you will be able to see many different ways this can be accomplished.

Comment: I thought providing specific answers to specific questions is what SE was about. As for other questions, I did check them out, and neither of the geolocation techniques listed there apply to my case. I specifically don't see how my question is "opinion-based"

Comment: It's Opinion Based because we can only guess. This isn't a "specific question" since we are not going to check out this site to figure out how it works. You never said that you checked out the other questions and I see that you only now added a new item that is from the other questions. The reality is that there are a lot of ways that a site can perform geolocation, as you can see from the *many* questions we have here on that topic.

Comment: For instance, in some of the other questions, it is suggested that your browser's timezone can be used. Keep going through the other questions to rule out things,

Comment: Maybe it's not that the site is associating your browser with your country; maybe it is that the site is associating your browser with **you**.  It seems like you are using a pretty unique configuration with your browser, so it may be possible that this site is able to uniquely fingerprint your browser.  If you run the test at https://coveryourtracks.eff.org/, what does it show?

Comment: @mti2935 it says I have "strong protection against Web tracking", and that I'm blocking tracking ads and invisible trackers. I don't see anything suspicious in the report, and certainly nothing Russia-related. It does say I have a very unique fingerprint, but that's likely due to my weird screen resolution and otherwise ancient specs. This also doesn't explain why I wouldn't be able to access from my phone

Comment: The site is a little confusing in that it says you have 'strong protection against web tracking', but yet, you have a very unique fingerprint.  If you have a unique fingerprint (as apparently you do), then you can easily be tracked.  Your previous activity at that site (or elsewhere on the web) may have revealed that your location is in Russia, and now they are able to tie you to that previous activity due to your unique fingerprint.  To solve the problem, you might want try using [Tails](https://tails.net/).

Comment: @mti2935 I don't deny having a unique fingerprint, but that still doesn't explain not being able to access the website with any of my devices, all of which have very different configurations.

Comment: Maybe those devices eacn have unique fingerprints as well.

Comment: A lot of trouble for a website to go into in order to block lil old me. [this website](https://www.wfaa.com/) also blocks me, though gives no explanation